# Como obrigar que diretiva so funcione se estiver dentro de uma diretiva específica?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou tentando fazer com que as diretivas ngPanelHead, ngPanelBody e ngPanelFoot necessitem estar dentro da diretiva ngPanel, caso contrario um erro seja apresentado no console. Tentei com require porem não está funcionando. Estou utilizando a versão 1.4.8 do AngularJS.

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('ngPanel', panel)
  .directive('ngPanelHead', panelHead)
  .directive('ngPanelBody', panelBody)
  .directive('ngPanelFoot', panelFoot);

function panel() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<section class="o-panel" ng-transclude></section>'
  }

  return directive;
}

function panelHead() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    // require: '^ngPanel',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<header class="o-panel__head" ng-transclude></header>'
  }

  return directive;
}

function panelBody() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    // require: '^ngPanel',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<article class="o-panel__body" ng-transclude></article>'
  }

  return directive;
}

function panelFoot() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    // require: '^ngPanel',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<footer class="o-panel__foot" ng-transclude></footer>'
  }

  return directive;
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Uma observação, não inicie o nome dos seus `directives` com `ng`, os `directives` do Angular possuem esse prefixo, sendo assim, você pode acidentalmente criar um já existente. Utilize o seu próprio prefixo, ex.: `bwPanel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O parâmetro `require` é a maneira correta de descrever requerimentos de dependência na definição da `Directive`.

```
.directive('subDiretiva', function() {
    return {
        scope: { data: "=" },
        require: ['?^^diretivaPai1', '?^^diretivaPai2'],  // Lista de possíveis diretivas-pai
        template: '<button></button>'
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, diretivaParenteCtrl) {
              //conteúdo do link aqui            
              };
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Angular você fez este teste? Talvez seja algum problema na versão do Angular pois na versão 1.4.8 não funciona.

Comment: @BrunoWego o teste da documentação do Angular funciona para mim - 'Creating directives that Communicate', https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive